# How to transfer same email address into Laravel Forge from Hostgator?

Tags: php, laravel, server, hosting, forge

I was using **Hostgator** and **Cpanel** and I recently start using **Forge** server for my laravel application. I want to use the same email address **myname@mydomain.com** in my Forge server. I want to change my **DNS** in my Godaddy account to point to forge and stop using Hostgator.

The question is how to keep the same **myname@mydomain.com** email address? because I used all of my social media and many other websites with this email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the same email address in the new server or you could use gmail to host your email which is about $5 per month.